# Android: distanceTo() wrong values

Tags: android, gps, location, distance

I am writing an application for tracking my route.
I am requesting updates from GPS every minute and it works fine.
It shows me my exact point.
When I want to calculate distance between current point and previous one it works ok, but form time to time it calculates distance totaly wrong (I moved about 200m and it retuned me a value over 10km). 
Does anyone know why this could happen?

Here is the function which I use:

```
iRoute += myGPSLocation.distanceTo(prevLocation);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try outputing the values of `myGPSLocation` and `prevLocation`. If those seem reasonable, and it still gives a wierd answer it may be of the accuracy of the measurements.

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would tell you the dist to the last point but instead sum up the total distance traveled. Can you show more code please?

Answer (score 1):

distanceTo() works correctly. 
The error is on your side, most probable algorithmic one, e.g if there is no GPS fix available, and the phone takes a GSM cell based location, this of course can be off by 1000m.

For your app that probably wants to sum up the distance travelled, take only GPS fixes, don't use another LocationProvider than GPS!

Comment: The error he described occurs more often when using Emulator, even today in 2016. The problem disappears on physical device.

Comment: @bold This has nothing to do with distance to, which just mathematicaly calculates the distance between two lat,lon coordinates. This calculation always work. What might not work (in emulator) is the value of lastValid location. So distancTo is called with wrong input data.

Comment: I've checked the values in debugger. The method receives correct values (almost exact same lat long and dest lat long), but mResults outputs entirely wrong values. The result should be under 10, but outputs something higher than 350.

Comment: the difference between 10m and 350m cannot be seen by looking at "almost" the same values. Just post the exact values as seen in the debugger; what is location.lat, lon and other.lat, lon? Print them out to the console, together with the distance value calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using google's Location.distancebetween & location.distanceto functions. They don't work consistently.

Instead use the direct formula to calculate the distance:

```
double distance_between(Location l1, Location l2)
{
    //float results[] = new float[1];
    /* Doesn't work. returns inconsistent results
    Location.distanceBetween(
            l1.getLatitude(),
            l1.getLongitude(),
            l2.getLatitude(),
            l2.getLongitude(),
            results);
            */
    double lat1=l1.getLatitude();
    double lon1=l1.getLongitude();
    double lat2=l2.getLatitude();
    double lon2=l2.getLongitude();
    double R = 6371; // km
    double dLat = (lat2-lat1)*Math.PI/180;
    double dLon = (lon2-lon1)*Math.PI/180;
    lat1 = lat1*Math.PI/180;
    lat2 = lat2*Math.PI/180;

    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double d = R * c * 1000;

    log_write("dist betn "+
            d + " " +
            l1.getLatitude()+ " " +
            l1.getLongitude() + " " +
            l2.getLatitude() + " " +
            l2.getLongitude()
            );

    return d;
}
```

Comment: elaborate on "doesn't work consistently." my guess is you're algorithm is pretty compute intensive and assumes sea level spherical earth, which is a lot of baggage.